# Determinar los 5 elementos que mas se registran en una tabla de base de datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Existen en laravel 5 algún método para determinar los 5 elementos mas se han insertado en una tabla de base de datos.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿es como hacer un conteo de una columna y ver cuáles están en el top 5?

Comment: exacto, esa es la idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe algo así en Laravel, ni en el Query Builder ni en Eloquent, toca hacerla de una forma un poco manual:

```
DB::table('comentarios')->select('post_id', DB::raw('COUNT(post_id) AS posts'))
        ->groupBy('post_id')
        ->orderBy('posts', 'DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

Sin embargo hay una pequeña esperanza si tienes relaciones establecidas con dicha tabla, por ejemplo posts relacionados con comentarios, lo cual nos permitiría contar la cantidad de los comentarios en la relación (asumiendo que queramos contar cantidad de comentarios) y ordenar dicho conteo:

```
Post::withCount('comentarios')            
   ->orderBy('comentarios_count', 'desc')
   ->take(5)                         
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

lo plantee de esta forma revisando su respuesta:

```
$ventas = VentasProductos::withCount('producto')
                        ->orderBy('producto_count', 'desc')
                        ->take(5)
                        ->get();
```

pero en la vista me muestra los elementos repetidos, me cree esta linea de código pero no me elimina uno de los elementos repetidos:

```
if($ventas){
        foreach($ventas as $key=>$venta){
           if(array_key_exists($venta->id, $ventas)){
                unset($ventas[$key]);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: intenta usar distinct() en tu consulta